# Hide div from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script that brings up some things that I don't want (a selector).

The script brings up a div class named "selector", and I don't want that div class to show. (I have no access to the css files)

Here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.setAttribute("language", "javascript");
     script.src = "http://js.sbrfeeds.com/js";
     script.id = "widget-main-script";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Is there any way to put some code in the above script that will hide the div "selector" when loaded?

Basically, I want what's circled in the picture to not show, and it is in a div class name "selector".

Image here: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/f385.png

Comment: type attribute is optional, language attribute is deprecated.

Comment: in html5 it is still necessary for older browsers like all IE browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a legitimate answer, but I ended up just hiding what I needed to be hid using a div class. Just throwing that here in case someone else needs it. You could also use a png file if it's an awkward shape to hide. Mine was just rectangular though.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selector')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Mind you, before you run that, you need to make sure your script fully loaded. Is there a reason you don't just add the script as a script tag so it will load when the page loads? Then you don't have to worry about all that mumbo jumbo.

Comment: I put this in and it didn't do anything. How would I put it in so it loads when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Div has an ID (and you are using JQuery), you could do something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAQL6/)

```
$('#selDiv').removeClass('selector');
```

If you aren't using JQuery, you could do this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAQL6/1/)

```
document.getElementById("selDiv").className = "";
```

Comment: the div id is "container" and selector is a class in that ID. I tried your solution and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
var css = '.selector { display : none}',
    header = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

header.appendChild(style);
```

This will create a  tag at header and then you can hide your element. Additionally you can set other CSS properties. Not sure this will work in your situation.

Comment: Sabbir, you can't hide it before the guy loads the script. He is saying the script creates a DOM element with the class `selector`.